# How to group and filter Sharepoint webservice XML response in Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I have a need to send automated emails based on Sharepoint list. I am able to retrieve the response and have code to send emails. But the email message body needs to be dynamic and need response date to be grouped. I am thinking of converting service response to represented as hashmap and use that hashmap to send targeted emails. Below is the sample of service response:

```
  <rs:data ItemCount="10">
     <z:row ows_Owner='1111@xxx.com' ows_Stories='Story1' ows_Program='Program1' />
     <z:row ows_Owner='1111@xxx.com' ows_Stories='Story2' ows_Program='Program1' />
     <z:row ows_Owner='1111@xxx.com' ows_Stories='Story3' ows_Program='Program2' />
     <z:row ows_Owner='1111@xxx.com' ows_Stories='Story4' ows_Program='Program2' />
     <z:row ows_Owner='2222@xxx.com' ows_Stories='Story5' ows_Program='Program1' />
     <z:row ows_Owner='2222@xxx.com' ows_Stories='Story6' ows_Program='Program1' />
     <z:row ows_Owner='2222@xxx.com' ows_Stories='Story7' ows_Program='Program1' />
     <z:row ows_Owner='2222@xxx.com' ows_Stories='Story8' ows_Program='Program2' />
     <z:row ows_Owner='2222@xxx.com' ows_Stories='Story9' ows_Program='Program2' />
     <z:row ows_Owner='2222@xxx.com' ows_Stories='Story10' ows_Program='Program2' />
  </rs:data>
```

What would be the best way to group and iterate the above data using powershell to send an email with body containing message with 'Stories' grouped by 'Program'. For ex: email sent to to '1111@xxx.com' will have message body as:

- Program1

  - Story1
  - Story2
- Program2

  - Story3
  - Story4

**Update:**
Here is the pseudo code to better explain my requirement -

```
select unique $owners from rs:row

foreach $owner in $owners
{     $messageBody =""
    foreach $program in rs:row where ows_owner=$owner
    {
        $messageBody += $program "<br />
        foreach $story in rs:row where ows_owner=$owner and ows_program=$program
        $messageBody += $story "<br />
     }
         sendmail $owner, $messageBody 
}
```

Just need code to easily achieve this in powershell especially filtering the data based on 'owner' and 'program' attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create custom PowerShell objects from the `<row>` nodes and then use [`Group-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849907.aspx) for grouping them by program:

```psh
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.xml'

$nsm = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xml.NameTable)
$nsm.AddNamespace('rs', 'http://...')  # replace with correct namespace URI

$xml.SelectSingleNode('//rs:data', $nsm) | select -Expand row | % {
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
    Program = $_.ows_Program
    Story   = $_.ows_Stories
  }
} | group Program | select Name, @{n='Stories';e={$_.Group.Story}}
```

If grouping is not an option you could build a data structure of nested hashtables like this:

```psh
$data = @{}
$xml.SelectSingleNode('//rs:data', $nsm) | select -Expand row | % {
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
    Owner   = $_.ows_Owner
    Program = $_.ows_Program
    Story   = $_.ows_Stories
  }
} | % {
  if (-not $data.Contains($_.Owner)) {
    $data[$_.Owner] = @{ $_.Program = @() }
  } elseif (-not $data[$_.Owner].Contains($_.Program)) {
    $data[$_.Owner][$_.Program] = @()
  }
  $data[$_.Owner][$_.Program] += $_.Story
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @Ansgar. While your solution does the work of grouping the 'stories' by 'program' but we need to group them by 'owner' as well so that we can send emails with program and stories related to specific owner. If it helps this is what I am thinking in terms of algotrithm -

Comment: I will update my original post with pseudo code that I think will work as solution.

Comment: Thanks @Ansgar for updated solution. This works perfectly. By enumerating through $data I get the expected result.